# Event delegation, Event.target vs Event.currentTarget

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In [MDN Event.target reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) there is an example about implementing event delegation:

#### Event delegation example

```
// Assuming there is a 'list' variable containing an instance of an  
// HTML ul element.
function hide(e) {
    // Unless list items are separated by a margin, e.target should be  
    // different than e.currentTarget
    e.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

list.addEventListener('click', hide, false);

// If some element (<li> element or a link within an <li> element for  
// instance) is clicked, it will disappear.
// It only requires a single listener to do that
```

#### Unclear part of the example

What i don't understand in the example is this comment:

```
// Unless list items are separated by a margin, e.target should be  
// different than e.currentTarget
```

#### Question

How can margin on `<li>` elements make difference between `Event.target` and `Event.currentTarget`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have in mind what makes `event.target` different than `event.currentTarget` as stated in [MDN Event.currentTarget reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

I think the point is that if there's no margin, then it'll be impossible to click directly on the `ul` since the `li` elements will entirely fill its space.

If there *is* a margin, then it'll at least be *possible* to click the `ul`, in which case `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` will be the same.

```js
function hide(e) {
    document.querySelector("pre").textContent += 'e.target = ' + e.target.nodeName + ", e.currentTarget = " + e.currentTarget.nodeName + "\n";
}

document.querySelector("#list").addEventListener('click', hide, false);
```

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: blue;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
<ul id="list">
  <li>click me
  <li>click me
  <li>click me
</ul>
```

Comment: Great part of my bad understanding was that i didn't read this:   "`event.currentTarget` always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred." - from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget Maybe you could just add this quote to your answer for future searches on this subject. Thanks!

Comment: @l0lander: It's a community wiki, so feel free to edit as needed.